# Cloud texture type in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

where to find the **clouds texture type** in node editor while using cycles? it is there while using displace modifier but not in node editor.

Comment: Cycles doesn't use the same procedural textures as BI. See [the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Textures) for a list of Cycles textures. The noise texture should be pretty much the same as clouds.

Comment: thanks, so is there a work around if i want to use the cloud texture i used in the displace modifier as a base for my texture??

Answer (score 7):

**blender internal clouds**
[image: internal clouds]
all default settings, shadeless material.

**cycles noise**
[image: cycles noise]
Niose texture *Scale* set to 8. All rest left to defaults. Cycles shadeless material, with a *RGB Curves* node to boost the contrast in the *Noise Texture*.

---

With those few settings changed you can get the cycles noise texture look very much like the blender internal clouds texture.

Comment: if only i was using simple noise, i m using voronoi f2-f1. i have been using multiple displacement. thanks for your suggestion.